# SQL Server CE 4.0 network share access

Tags: oledb, sql-server-compact

In our application we are planning to use SQL Server CE 4.0 using OLE DB. The connection string is shown below.

```
Dim strConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\pc137\d\desktop\mydb.sdf; SSCE:Database Password='password';"
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection            
conn = New OleDbConnection(strConn)            
conn.Open()
```

This one worked for both the local and network share files (`.sdf`)

We tried to connect using Visual Studio for the network share we get following error

> SQL Server Compact does not support opening database files on a network share.

We have referred [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/646333/sql-ce-4-0-no-longer-supports-opening-files-on-a-network-share) [links](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d983dbdf-6be9-4f11-b76f-5a0ada198363/sqlce-35-sp2-on-network-share?forum=sqlce)

So is it allowed to connect SQL Server CE 4.0 using OLE DB in network share?

Does it cause any other problem?

Comment: The error message and link seem pretty clear that it isn't supported. Why not utilize SQL Express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not supported. And using the Oledb provider from a .net application is not supported either, use the Ado.net provider (System.Data.SqlServerCe)

Comment: But using OLE DB as shown in original post we are able to connect to database in a network share. So how it worked ?

Comment: That you can connect does not mean that it is supported, and you will run into issues with for example parameters and image columns

Comment: Can you please explain what problem occurs related to image columns. Also which parameters do you mean?

Comment: Image/ntext columns cannot be selected via the OLEDB provider, and parameterized SQL does not work as expected

Comment: So if i use System.Data.SqlServerCe can I access n/w share?

Comment: No you cannot, it is not supported, use SQL Server Express instead

Comment: Ok.thank u. Can you pls look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548397/deploying-application-using-sql-ce-4-0-to-work-both-in-32-and-64-bit-pc